# Share the HttpSession or Cookie objects on different domains

Tags: jakarta-ee, cookies, cross-domain, tomcat6, httpsession

I have an issue in accessing the `HttpSession` / `Cookie` objects among the different domains in same Application. The site serve on both the domain `http://` and `https://` within same application (context) of Tomcat. The issue is the `HttpSession` / `Cookie` objects which are created on `http://` domain or `https://` domain vice versa are not able to access . the domain url will change when the url redirects from `http://` to `https://` within the same context.
Is it possible to share the objects of different domains with different urls of the same Context application in Tomcat.